Change size of small, medium and large in leaflet-markercluster
I would like to change the size limits for the 3 sizes small, medium and large in markercluster.
I have found it in the leaflet.markercluster.js file:
_defaultIconCreateFunction: function (e) {
  var t=e.getChildCount(),i=" marker-cluster-";
  return i+=t<10?"small":t<100?"medium":"large"

But I would like to change it in the js-file that loads my map instead, so that I do not have to remember to change it every time I get a new version.
All I have en regards to markercluster in that file is:
var clusterLayer = L.markerClusterGroup({
  showCoverageOnHover: false,
  maxClusterRadius: 40,
  spiderLegPolylineOptions: {
    weight: 5,
    color: '#E0AA5E',
    opacity: 0.9
  }
});


Use the iconCreateFunction option of MCG:

you can provide your own function for creating the Icon for the clustered markers. The default implementation changes color at bounds of 10 and 100, but more advanced uses may require customising this.

Therefore in your case you could do something like:
var clusterLayer = L.markerClusterGroup({
  iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
    // Adapted from https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/src/MarkerClusterGroup.js#L821-L834
    var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();

    var c = ' marker-cluster-';
    if (childCount < LOWER_LIMIT) {
      c += 'small';
    } else if (childCount < UPPER_LIMIT) {
      c += 'medium';
    } else {
      c += 'large';
    }

    return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + childCount + ' <span aria-label="markers"></span>' + '</span></div>', className: 'marker-cluster' + c, iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });
  },
  // Other options...
});


Exactly what I needed... Strange that they would mention that and not have an example like yours in the readme...
